# At what point do dopamine/serotonin receptors become downregulated/upregulated?

Tags: neuroscience, psychology, dopamine

It's well known that behaviors like [pornography viewing lead to dopamine receptor downregulation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4600144/) to compensate for the extreme stimulation. Obviously, drugs like methamphetamine would lead to an even more profound downregulation if used.

When are receptors in this context downregulated or not? If pornography downregulates dopamine, does playing video games do the same but to a lesser extent? If this trend of stimulation = downregulation continues, do I get a mini-downregulation when I eat chocolate or drink coffee or find $20 on the ground? If I deprive myself of stimulation for a certain period of time, can I get to the point where my receptors are upregulated enough to get video game level stimulation from reading, for example? If I listened to music all day long would that deplete my ability to enjoy other things?

I assume I have many incorrect assumptions in my analysis here and I'd like to know what I'm missing.